# error while configuring the iis server ( HTTP error 500.19 )

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to configure IIS local server but I get the following error while accessing the site:

`The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid`

***Details***

Module: IIS Web Core

Notification: BeginRequest

Handler:    Not yet determined

Error Code: 0x80070005

Config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Logon Method:  Not yet determined

Logon User: Not yet determined

Comment: The URL and the file path should have been in the error page too. Focus on that and you should know which file cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs for one of the following reasons:

You are using IIS 7.0 on a computer that is running Windows Vista. Additionally, you configure the Web site to use UNC Passthrough authentication to access a remote Universal Naming Convention (UNC) share.

The IIS_IUSRS group does not have the appropriate permissions for the ApplicationHost.config file, for the Web.config file, or for the virtual/application directories of IIS.

Click [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942055) for details and methods for solving the problem.